# rootObj replaceObjectAtIndex, how can i get the valueForKey?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i'm trying to replace a value in my NSDictionnary but i cannot reach the part i'm looking for

I would like to use this method, or kind of...

i have a NSDictionnary and i want to replace this :

> [[rootObj objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"check"]

there is this method :

> rootObj replaceObjectAtIndex:<#(NSUInteger)#> withObject:<#(id)#>

but i cannot acces to the valueForKey... how can i reach it ?

Thanks !

Comment: rootObj a mutableArray? and it is contain dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code for replace code

**EDIT: Update answer according to user's match**

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
NSDictionary *oldDict = (NSDictionary *)[rootObj objectAtIndex:0]; 
[newDict addEntriesFromDictionary:oldDict];
[newDict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"check"];
[rootObj replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:newDict];
```

In the above example i want to replace the object of @"Sales Qty"
so i have create dictionary and set the object in those dictionary then just set the value for @"Sales Qty" key and replace the whole dictionary in array

If you have still problem then let me know

Comment: thanks man, i used it, work perfect but i modify stuff because i didnt need the for and if :)

used this : 

      NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            NSDictionary *oldDict = (NSDictionary *)[rootObj objectAtIndex:0];
            [newDict addEntriesFromDictionary:oldDict];
            [newDict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"check"];
            [rootObj replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:newDict]; 

thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Firstly get all keys like this:

```
    NSArray *arrKeys = [yourDictionary allKeys];
```

Now replace like this say u want replace second object :

```
 if([arrKeys objectAtIndex:1]) //key for second Object
 {
   [yourDictionary setObject:yourNewValueHere forKey:[arrKeys objectAtIndex:1]]; //it overwrites value
 }
```